# Can Greek letter names be declined?

Tags: greek, declension, alphabet

There seems to be solid evidence that [Latin letter names were indeclinable](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/7294/406).

But in Greek, several letters' names *do* fit into standard declension patterns: *sigma*, for instance, [might actually be a *-ma* noun from *sizō* "to hiss"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/10781/406). And *gamma* and *digamma* **look** like *-ma* nouns, even if they historically aren't.

So: do we ever find *sigmata* or *gammata*? Or, less obviously, *alphai* and *betai*? Or are all letter names indeclinable in Greek?

EDIT: I'd also be interested in cases of *omicra* and *epsila*, even though those names are later. But first and foremost I'm curious about usage in the classical period.

Comment: Perhaps more obvious than *alphai* and *betai* would be *omicra* and *epsila*. Different letters suggest different kinds of plurals, and I would be interested in seeing whether they all behave the same.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta True! I left off omega, omicron, epsilon, and ypsilon because those are later names, and I'm not sure they were actually treated as *names* or just as modifiers on the names (that is, if the plural of *o micron* would be *o micra*, with the *o* still being indeclinable).

Answer (score 6):

LSJ on [Σ](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.67:1.LSJ):

> B the name σίγμα ( σῖγμα) was usu. indeclinable, τοῦ σῖγμα Pl. l.c., Cra.402e, 427a, Ath.10.455c, Lyd.Mens.1.21 (v.l. σίγματος) ; τῷ σῖγμα Gal.UP2.14, al.; τῶν σῖγμα Pl.Com.30; τὰ σίγμα τὰ ἐπὶ τῶν ἀσπίδων X.HG4.4.10, cf. Hellad. ap. Phot.Bibl.p.532 B.; **later declined, τοῦ σίγματος Eust.1389.15; σίγμασιν Id.905.7.**

Comment: Perfect, this is just what I was looking for! What does the "v.l." mean before _sigmatos_? And what time period are _Eust._ and _Id._ from?

Comment: v(aria) l(ectio). id(em). But who is Eust?

Comment: Eustathius of Thessalonike, a 12C Byzantine scholar.